# An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection". 'boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(char)'

Tags: eclipse

Requesting Java AST from selection

```
An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
'boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(char)'
```

I use eclipse 2022-03 and it keeps poping up this error log. Can anyone help me? Tks so muck.

I dont have any idea where this problem come from

Comment: Eclipse 2022-03 is 3 releases behind. Please make sure that the software you are using is up to date before asking. If the error continues to occur, go to the _Error Log_ view and copy the error and paste it into your question. It is probably caused by a plugin you have installed.

Comment: i faced this problem when i install spring tool but even when i uninstall that the error still go on. I tried to uninstall en install eclipse again and everything seem okk until now. I think this problem is caused by spring tool

Comment: Great, that it is working. Make sure to keep both up to date, Eclipse and Spring Tools.

Comment: I had the same problem when I also installed the Spring Tool. Gone as soon as I updated my Eclipse from Help -> Check for Updates...

Answer (score 13):

Menu window > preferences > java > Editor > mark occurrences and disable : mark occurrences

Enjoy!

Comment: And now occurrences of a variable aren't highlighted, which is a feature I find helpful. An actual fix would be better...

Comment: This Solution also worked for me. But in Mac Book   navigation is like this   :  Eclipse --> Setting ---> Java---> Editor ---> mark occurrences , and uncheck all  then apply

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the library ICU4J - this method was removed:

boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(char)

Solution

- find all com.ibm.icu*.jar; you can use Installation Details > (tab) Configuration
- remove the newest version (or rename the extension)

In my case I've found:

```
*** Plug-in Registry:
com.ibm.icu (67.1.0.v20200706-1749) "ICU4J" [Starting]
com.ibm.icu (72.1.0.v20221115-2007) "ICU4J" [Active]

*** Current Install Configuration:

Id: com.ibm.icu, Version: 67.1.0.v20200706-1749, Location: reference:file:/root/.p2/pool/plugins/com.ibm.icu_67.1.0.v20200706-1749.jar
Id: com.ibm.icu, Version: 72.1.0.v20221115-2007, Location: reference:file:../../../../home/xxxxx/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.23.0_516645266_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/com.ibm.icu_72.1.0.v20221115-2007.jar
```

After removing the second jar, Eclipse started working again ;-)

Comment: **Do not do that! You will wreck your Eclipse installation by doing so!** Other plugins might require the newer version causing errors on run time. Removing a JAR, as described here, will break your installation so that some plugins can no longer be installed, uninstalled or upgraded, or will not work as expected.

Comment: In principle, I agree. But... the problem to solve was when you installed and uninstalled the plugin, and Eclipse stopped working. Apparently, the uninstall process wasn't completed.

Comment: No, in principle, you do stupid things by guessing wrong from trial and error without any knowing how things work here. Again, applying your answer causes harm (how much harm depends on the plugins you have and what features do you use). If you do not want to fool others, delete your answer.

Comment: @howlger, I have this issue, but can't update to the latest eclipse due to other issues.
If I can't update eclipse, what would your suggestion be?

Comment: Looks like this specifically changed in version 70.1 when they changed the API signature from char to int:
https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-21655

Comment: @PaulCarew There are safe and well documented ways to update a single plugin. But better spend your time fixing what's stopping you from updating.

Comment: Unfortunately, by removing the indicated file, the Help->"Eclipse Marketplace..." option disappeared, although the problem was resolved. Re-entering the file didn't fix it, I had to reinstall Eclipse.
Personally, I do **not** recommend this method.

Answer (score 0):

Solved on Eclipse 2020-12 (4,18.0) by uninstalling the most recent plugin - Memory Analysis tool.

Comment: Don't do this. Eclipse 2020-12 is more than two years and nine releases behind. The confirmed solution is to use the current version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

When I started updating help->updates. it took three cycles to complete installations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for me following steps worked:

- uninstall the new plugin which caused the issue in "Help\Eclipse Markplace\Installed"
- delete new Installation and revert to old Installation in -> Help\About Eclipse Platform\Installation Details\Installation History
- close Eclipse and remove (or better move to an backup directory) the newest file of [eclipse Inatallation Path]/plugins/com.ibm.icu_*.jar
- start eclipse again

Comment: By default, not needed plugins will be removed next time you start Eclipse. So step three should not be needed.

Comment: yea should not. But somehow in my case it was needed

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue on Eclipse 2022-06 while installing "M2E - Complete Development Kit" & as I could not find any reference to com.ibm.icu to version upper to 67.1.0 on [Eclipse 2022-06's update site](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-06/202206151000/plugins/), I deduced the invalid dependency came from contacted update sites.
Indeed, unchecking "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" in the "Install New Software" view seems to solve the issue, at least with M2E.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error message.
And, I solve problem now.
[here is the web i see](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533599)

And i go to Help > About Ecplise IDE > Installation Details ,
and click first column Buildship:Eclipse plug-ins for Gradle.

After that ,there are some button at the bottom of this window ,one of those call update.
After update and restart , the problem solve.

Hope You can solve the problem.

Comment: Didn't fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in Eclipse STS.

Via the help menu -> About -> installation details and then  I could solve it.

Comment: How could you solve it?